# Publish An Application Update On Android - Market Without Deleting Local Database And Local Files

Tags: android, database

I published an application that stores data in a local database.

Now I have to publish an update to this application to fix some little bugs, but I am afraid that downloading and installing the update will delate the local database associated with the previous version.

I would like to know how the update system works. Will installing an update completely delete all the apk, files, databases associeted with the previous version?

If so, how can I avoid this in my code?

Comment: What would happen if I made some changes in my database of updated version? The user should want to uninstall the previous application and then download and install the updated version or simply update the application is enough?

Answer (score 3):

iShader, updates to an existing app in android market does not delete or alter the database (sqlite files), shared preferences or other files created using Android data Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but do i need to do any coding to update my DB

Comment: Only if you modified the schema. IF that is the case you need to write new upgrading code. You could test it locally by installing your application from the market, creating a new release build, and using adb install -r your_new_release_build_with_bug_fix.apk ... That is pretty much what the market will do to people with the old apk installed.

Comment: What would happen if I made some changes in my database of updated version? The user should want to uninstall the previous application and then download and install the updated version or simply update the application is enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the application version number in the manifest file.